# Why does my Python code take an extremely long time to execute?

Tags: python

I have a Python code snippet that I believe should terminate quickly, but it seems to take an extraordinarily long time to complete. The code is attempting to find the smallest value of `i` such that a valid image can be opened using the PIL (Python Imaging Library) module. However, even for relatively small values of `i`, the code runs for an extended period.

```
from PIL.Image import open as o

i = 0
while True:
    with open('f.png', 'wb') as a:
        a.write(i.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
    try:
        o('f.png')
        break
    except:
        i += 1

print(i)
```

I suspect there may be an issue with the code that is causing this prolonged execution time. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this delay and suggest any possible optimizations? Additionally, are there any alternative approaches or libraries that could achieve the same objective more efficiently?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Yes it is nonzero.

Comment: ...okay, so you're looping through all possible files until you come up with one that's a valid PNG? How many bytes long _is_ the smallest possible PNG?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what i'm doing.

Comment: Once you know that: How many iterations do you expect will be necessary, and why do you think that the brute-force search will be fast? (Brute-force algorithms usually _aren't_ fast, unless you have reason to believe a valid solution will come up quite early; is there in fact reason to have such a belief here?)

Comment: ...that said, it would make things _less slow_ if you kept everything in-memory instead of getting the filesystem involved. Not necessarily less-slow enough to make you happy, but less-slow nonetheless.

Comment: Your right that would be a perfect idea but i think it still be slow.

Comment: There is no iterating over files in your example, just an attempt to write an integer to a file to get _some sort of valid signature_ that lets PIL identify it as an image. This is going to take a very, very, very long time to happen, as PIL will attempt ot verify the metadata in the content that gets written. _What_ are you actually trying to achieve? (And don't swallow all exceptions - that makes something very hard to debug - handle those that you intend to handle)

Comment: That's right, _because you're running a brute-force search_. I don't see a problem with Python-the-language doing something wrong here; I see a poorly-chosen algorithm for the task at hand, which isn't necessarily a problem that fits inside our scope (building an algorithm that can _intelligently_ build sample data to exercise codepaths is an active research topic; there are teams that have had substantial success, and pointing such a tool against a PNG parser is generally the appropriate way to go here).

Comment: [This page](https://garethrees.org/2007/11/14/pngcrush/) says the smallest answer is 67 bytes, which suggests this will take around [10^161](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2**%288*67%29) iterations to complete.

Comment: I created a 1x1 pixel image with PIL and the size was 69 bytes so i wanted to know what is in those other bytes except 1x1 pixel?

Comment: The easier way to answer that would be to start by reading the format specification.

Comment: Wikipedia can tell you that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#File_format  - a PNG file consists of a header and chunks, usually with pixel data run length encoded in one of the chunks. Start with the spec. Trying to brute force a valid format will not tell you what those values mean - you've just done the same as what you already have a file example showing.

Comment: BTW, a lot of the research in terms of constructing data to walk a code tree happens in the security community, around construction of new and better fuzzers; that's probably the direction you want to look in if you're curious about how someone would do better than brute-force. It's much too large a topic to fit inside a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: See https://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/ as an example of a sophisticated fuzzer that I'd expect would do a much better job, when handed a copy of a PNG parser, at finding its way to valid (as well as interestingly/bug-inducingly-invalid) inputs.

Comment: To be blunt, if you don't understand what's in a PNG file, then you are hardly in a position to research them.

Answer (score 4):

This is slow because you're trying to build something *by brute force* where the shortest possible answer is a 67-byte file.

Your code is only going to start testing possible 67-byte files after it's tried all possible 66-byte files, thus after writing 8**66 different files to disk.

That's testing 401,734,511,064,747,568,885,490,523,085,290,650,630,550,748,445,698,208,825,344 different files *before you even get to the minimum length that could possibly succeed* (and there are some possible files your code will *never* reach, since it doesn't try values where the first byte is all `0`s; so there are file formats for which this approach will never succeed at all).

Is it a surprise that it's slow?

---

If you want to generate a PNG file by analyzing a tool that parses them, that's a job for a fuzzer like [american fuzzy lop](https://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/).